# PHP preg_match question

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I match the three words in the following string with a Perl compatible regular expression?

word1#$word2#$word3

I don't know the actual words "word1, word2 and word3" in advance. I only know the separator, which is #$.

And I can't use the word boundary as I have a multibyte encoding. This means for instance that the string can contain non-ASCII characters like umlauts which are not detected by the \w control character.

Comment: Are you using Perl or some other language which claims to have Perl regular expressions?

Comment: @mixedpickles PHP ne Perl. Corrected title and tags.

Comment: Why the heck should this NOT be a real question??

Comment: Why are people marking this to be closed? It's certainly a valid programming question. If it's a duplicate, someone should link to the duplicates so that the author can find the original question and answer.

Comment: @eyelidlessness The question started life cloaked as a Perl question when in fact it is a PHP question. The answer to the question is not to use a regular expression but to use `explode` or `split` but the OP does not accept it because of information he is not sharing about the input. In short, it seems like answering this question requires ESP.

Comment: Sinan Ünür, I looked at the original revision of the question, and I can see how you misunderstood it but it did clearly identify "Perl compatible regular expression"—that is, PCRE—as the regex flavor in question. That's pretty helpful, where most presumably-regex questions hang improperly answered until the question poster identifies the flavor.

Comment: That said, yes, he selected the wrong "correct" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/(\w+)#\$(\w+)#\$(\w+)/
```

---

**Edit**   After your provided us with more information (see the comments to this answer):

```
/((?:[^#]+|#[^$])*)#\$((?:[^#]+|#[^$])*)#\$((?:[^#]+|#[^$])*)/
```

Comment: Can't use word boundary as the word could be virtually everything that does not consist of the two consecutive characters #$

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 'word1#$word2#$word3';
print $_, "\n" for split /#\$/, $x;
```

Comment: I guess he is asking about Regular expression

Comment: I need a regular expression here as this serves as subexpression only.

Comment: @mixedpickles: No, you cannot use split because you are not using Perl which is fine but you should identify your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = explode('#$', $str);
```

Regex is overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any string that has 2 `#`

```
/([^#]+)\#\$([^#]+)\#\$([^#]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

A split function might be useful although it depends what you want to do with the line.

here is an example though.

```
my $line = "word1#$word2#$word3"
my @words = split('#$', $line)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/([^#]*?)#\$([^#]*?)#\$([^#]*)/
```

Comment: This does not work for wor#d1#$word2#$word3
which would be valid as the separator is always a hash character following a dollar character

Comment: Would be useful to explain what this regex does instead of just dropping it here undocumented.